# How are variadic arguments treated by templates?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following function:

```
void f(...);
```

And the following structure:

```
template <class T>
struct s;

template <class R, class...A>
struct s<R(A...)>
{
    //...
};
```

How exactly does `s<decltype(f)>` get treated, considering its variadic argument type?

Comment: `decltype(f)` will not match against `R(A...)` (with `A` typelist) so `s<decltype(f)>` will not compile. You'd need `R(A......)` (a double ellipsis) to match it.

Comment: @ecatmur That would stop matching the non-variadic version of the function, wouldn't it?

Comment: It would. You'd need both specializations. And depending on what you are trying to achieve, you may need to go all out, like an [`std::is_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) implementation.